# DSi Data Recovery Process?

Tags: memory, hardware, digital-forensics

I have been asked to recover data from a Nintendo DSi device that has some critical pictures and audio on it.

After looking closely at the system, it appears that the memory must be integraded onto the board and will require some effort to attach it to something like a [Serial Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009T2ZR6W).

Any ideas on what kind of a process to follow in order to access such a memory device as is found on a DSi?

Comment: Can you dump this however you please or do you need to establish/follow a process that will hold up under legal scrutiny?

Comment: @dsasmblr it doesn't have to be used in an actual criminal investigation per se, so I suppose there is some flexibility with the methodology here...

Comment: In that case, I recommend spending some time around the GBATemp forum -- perhaps even posing your question there instead. Posts like this one (https://gbatemp.net/threads/tutorial-noob-friendly-nand-dumping-2ds-3ds-3ds-xl-n3ds-n3ds-xl.414498/) should lead you down the right path.